# Is it possible to pass variable to Tcl through makefile

Tags: makefile, tcl

I may need some help here.

The scenario is,
let's say, I have a TCL script "test.tcl", which contains something like below,

```
set condition true

if {$condition==true} {
    puts "Message1"
} elseif {$condition==false} {
    puts "Message2"
}
```

Then I have another makefile to simply run this TCL script, in which,

```
runScript:
    tclsh test.tcl
```

When I run it with

```
make runScript
```

is there any way that variable "**condition**" inside TCL script can be somehow provided by Makefile, rather than writing inside TCL script itself?

Any help would be grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find a way to pass that variable to your script when you invoke it from the command line, then you can use the same method from your makefile.  This isn't related to make or makefiles, it's just a TCL question.

Googling "set tcl variable from command line" got me to this page: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl38.html

So, something like this might work:

```
$ cat Makefile
runScript:
       myvalue=true tclsh test.tcl

$ cat test.tcl
set condition $env(myvalue)
  ...
```

But my days of writing TCL are far, far behind me.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. This works on my side.

Comment: The usual options are either command line arguments (which you need to parse out of the `argv` global variable) or environment variables (in the `env` global array).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to pass information to a Tcl script (or any command line program) is via arguments:

**Makefile**

```
CONDITION = true
runScript:
        tclsh test.tcl ${CONDITION}
```

Inside the Tcl script the command line arguments can be accessed via the `argv` variable.

**test.tcl**

```
if {[llength $argv] != 1} {
    puts stderr "Usage: $argv0 <condition>"
    exit 1
}
lassign $argv condition
```

Comment: This works for TCL script alone. But I might show a not very good example. Actually I’m not simply calling tclsh to run this script, so this argv method doesn’t quite suit here. But thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Then update your question to describe what you really want to do.